# bootstrap not showing dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap form that I have added a dropdown list.  When I click on the dropdown I see the list, but when I click on it doesn't show as selected it still shows "select Domain" all the time.  I found this link

> https://www.codeply.com/go/pTWA3jYWEv/bootstrap-bootstrap-dropdown-selected-value

I have modified it, but I am missing something cause it is not working for me.

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block dropdown-toggle" type="button"
          id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Select Domain
      <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item">Corp</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item">Domain2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item">Domain3</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item">Local</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
  var selText = $(this).text();
  $(this).parents('.dropdown').find('.btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block dropdown-toggle').html(selText+' <span class="caret"></span>');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for Bootstrap dropdown to work, add the following CDN references in the HTML document to the project. Additionally select `".dropdown-menu a"` to capture the clicked `<a>` element. The solution below provides an easy way to change the text of the `<button>` element whose id is `dropdown-button` when the dropdown button is clicked.

```js
$(".dropdown-menu a").click( function() {
  console.clear();
  console.log($(this).text());
  
  var selText = $(this).text();
  $('#dropdown-button').html(`${selText} <span class="caret"></span>`)
});
```

```css
.caret {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<!-- Add the following CDN references to the project. -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="dropdown">
  <!-- Added id attribute to this element. -->
  <button id="dropdown-button" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Select Domain
      <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item">Corp</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item">Domain2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item">Domain3</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item">Local</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```